# Make a function of SQL script usng Python's execute script

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, sqlite

I am working with a database in SQLite and am importing a bunch of csv files into my database. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell there is no way to add a primary key during the import, so I am using a work around in which I read in the csv file and use Pandas' `to_sql` and then `executescript`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv', header = 0, index_col = False, encoding = 'UTF-8')
df.to_sql(name = 'table1', con = conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

c.executescript('''
PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table1_alt;

/*create a new table with the same column names and types while
defining a primary key for the desired column*/
CREATE TABLE Ass_info_table (column1 INT,
                    column2 TEXT,
                    column3 INT,
                    column4 INT,
                    column5 INT,
                    column6 TEXT,
                    column7 TEXT,
                    column8 TEXT,
                    column9 TEXT,
                    column10 TEXT,
                    column11 TEXT,
                    column12 INT,
                    column13 INT,
                    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table1_alt;

DROP TABLE table1_alt;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;''')
```

This works just fine, but I have a bunch of csv files that I wanted to `glob` through and import them all in a loop. My problem is that in order to do that I need to figure out a way to get the names of the tables and columns into that SQL script in a function. That function can go as the table is imported into the database or after, it doesn't really matter.

Anyone who has any suggestions, it would be more than welcome!

Comment: Why not use SQLite command line to import CSVs into current, empty tables that has a integer primary key in place since per SQLite FAQs: [A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)?

Comment: are you using pd.to_sql and script separately?

Comment: mad_ I am using them separately as simply importing the csv into the database gives me a table with no primary key.

Parfait, if I do that then I have a table with a primary key already assigned, right? Which I don't want.

Comment: Like any database's autoincrements (or sequences if using Oracle and identity in SQL Server), the primary key will autoincrement with each new record. Nothing is assigned ahead of time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the csv files already have a unique ID built in which I need to use as the primary key (for relational purposes), so I have to use what's already there and assign a primary key to one of the existing columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you can parse table name and column names from csv or other sources then you can make query before passing it to execution function.

Example:

```
table_name="P_data"
query_template="SELECT * FROM  {0}"
final_query=query_template.format(table_name)
```

and then you can pass final_query into execution. I like making final query via templates but you can do it directly.

```
query_template="SELECT * FROM  {0}".format(table_name)"
```

Hope it will help you.